# How to display resources of a restful API

Tags: rest, http, lending-club-api

I am trying to display the resources and associated subresources of a restful API I am working with (https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor//). If resources aren't documented, is there any way to find them?

Answer (score 1):

There presently is not a standard way to discover restful API operations like there is with WSDL based soap web services.

Documentation from the API provider is the best way to learn.